# Will my meatloaf cook if the sauce is mixed into the meat

Tags: meatloaf

I accidentally mixed the ingredients all together for my meatloaf. The recipe says to add the sauces on top but I've already mixed it in. Will it still cook and be edible?

Comment: Yes, it will cook, but you'll have to call it a casserole.

Answer (score 21):

It will cook, and be safe to eat.

However, depending on the ratio of sauce to solid ingredients, and how much binder (egg, etc.) is in your recipe, you might end up with [sloppy joe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloppy_joe) filling rather than a meatloaf.

Comment: If you can [edit your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/120888/edit) to provide your recipe, we might be able to make predictions with more certainty.

Answer (score 16):

I think the answer you are after is whether it will keep its shape and still be meatloafy. Even with a recipe I'd be guessing what the consistency would be, so I'll give you my approach instead. Grab a small amount of the mix and roll it into a ball. If it keeps its shape and is relatively firm then you're good to go, if it sags or falls apart it's not going to hold together. You can also make a little ball and microwave it for 30 seconds and see whether it holds together when cooked. I use this method to test for seasoning with meatballs and mealoaves (meatloafs? meatlofii? No idea as to the plural here), and to check the consistency.

If your mix doesn't hold together well enough then you have two options:

1. Add more binder: more breadcrumbs will bring it all back together, but if it's really loose you may have to add so much it will make the result bready, which isn't desirable
2. Cook it up and serve it over a starch such as rice, mashed potatoes or pasta, depending on the flavoring. You could also make a shepherds pie or cottage pie with it. Or, as @A_SOO suggests, you could make sloppy joes

Comment: I'd go with meatlopodes ;)

Comment: "meatlopodes" is my new favorite word.

Comment: a secondary question is if you use a mix of meats in your meatloaf, why isn't it then meatsloaf?

Comment: bread and egg (mixed in sequence, not together) can add quite a lot more structure than either alone.

Comment: @LightBender "Meat" is an countable noun, so "meatloaf" already covers that case :)